# ¿Cómo convierto una celda con separador de miles en apache poi?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Aqui tengo el estiloNumero con el setDataFormat, pero no me aparecen los numeros con los puntos en las milésimas

```
CellStyle estiloNumeros = archivoExcel.createCellStyle();
        Font numeros = archivoExcel.createFont();
        numeros.setFontName("Trebuchet MS");
        numeros.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 6);
        estiloNumeros.setFont(numeros);
        // estiloNumeros.setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("#.##0"));
        estiloNumeros.setVerticalAlignment(CellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER);
        estiloNumeros.setWrapText(true);
        estiloNumeros.setBorderTop(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
        estiloNumeros.setBorderLeft(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
        estiloNumeros.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
        estiloNumeros.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM); 
  estiloNumeros.setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("#.##0"));
```

Comment: Probaste con `#.##0,00`?

Comment: si, pero sigue saliendo como celda general sin puntos

Comment: Qué versión de POI usas y cómo estás usando el CellStyle? Cómo le estás poniendo el dato a la celda? Por favor [edit] la pregunta y añadir la respuesta a estas preguntas :)

Comment: ¿Cuál localización (*Locale*) usas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba no usando uno de los formatos "custom" que pueda traer Excel y crea uno propio. Luego, cambia la aproximación para que SIEMPRE ponga dos decimales y sólo ponga el tercero cuando no sea cero.

```
estiloNumeros.setDataFormat(workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat("0.00#"));
```

Los ceros indican que siempre debe mostrarse esa cifra significativa. Los `#` se muestran sólo si es necesario (si no es cero, por ejemplo).